# R lm summary error

Tags: r, rstudio

Somehow my summary() function stopped working for lm regression outputs. To demonstrate the problem and error message that I get, I have run the example regression from "?lm":

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
lm.D90 <- lm(weight ~ group - 1) # omitting intercept

anova(lm.D9)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: weight
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
group      1 0.6882 0.68820  1.4191  0.249
Residuals 18 8.7292 0.48496               
summary(lm.D90)
Error in summary.lm(lm.D90) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(est, se, tval, 2 * pt(abs(tval), rdf, lower.tail = FALSE)) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

opar <- par(mfrow = c(2,2), oma = c(0, 0, 1.1, 0))
plot(lm.D9, las = 1)      # Residuals, Fitted, ...
par(opar)
```

The error message also appears for other lm commands for which I got the summary output in the past but from one second to the other R only give me now the above error message.

Even if I restart R studio or my computer the error message appears. Does anyone have a suggestion why this may be the case?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. maybe give us your code generating the above error message? and some sample data for input?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the example.

Comment: It's possible you have RStudio set to save your session. Try Session > Clear Workspace (make sure the checkbox is checked) then Session > Restart R and Clear Output.
Can you also run `sessionInfo()` and post the results?

Comment: Thank you for the last comment - it has solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It did run on my machine like so:

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
lm.D90 <- lm(weight ~ group - 1) # omitting intercept
anova(lm.D9) 
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: weight
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F) group      1 0.6882 0.68820  1.4191  0.249 Residuals 18 8.7292 0.48496               
summary(lm.D90)

Call: lm(formula = weight ~ group - 1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.0710 -0.4938  0.0685  0.2462  1.3690 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     groupCtl   5.0320     0.2202   22.85 9.55e-15 *** groupTrt   4.6610     0.2202   21.16 3.62e-14 ***
--- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6964 on 18 degrees of freedom Multiple R-squared:  0.9818,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.9798  F-statistic: 485.1 on 2 and 18 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Thanks Zahiro but when I am applying summary(lm.D90) it gives me the error message above. Summary() just stopped working on my computer for one second to the other...

Comment: did you install and new packages maybe masking 'summary' ?? try `conflicts(, TRUE)`

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of.

Comment: maybe edit the question to show exactly what you do and what you get. something sound fishy